# Use multiple cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport in the same page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

`cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` is not working properly when I use more than two `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` in the same page.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-virtual-scroll-dhdj1c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

In the above example, first dropdown is working properly. but in the second dropdown, getting blank space after scrolling the dropdown and open the dropdown again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wihTi.png)

```
    <mat-select [formControl]="multiSelectControl"  (openedChange)="openChange($event)"
        placeholder="Select">
        <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" [style.height.px]=5*48 >
            <mat-option *cdkVirtualFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
                >{{topping.viewValue}}</mat-option>
        </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<br>
<br>

<mat-form-field>
<mat-select [formControl]="multiSelectControl1"  (openedChange)="openChange1($event)"
    placeholder="Select">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" [style.height.px]=5*48 minBufferPx="200" maxBufferPx="400">
        <mat-option *cdkVirtualFor="let topping of toppingList1" [value]="topping"
            >{{topping.viewValue}}</mat-option>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

export class AppComponent {

  toppingList: any[] = [];
  toppingList1: any[] = [];

  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: true })
  cdkVirtualScrollViewPort: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: true })
  cdkVirtualScrollViewPort1: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  multiSelectControl = new FormControl();
  multiSelectControl1 = new FormControl();

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, readonly sd: ScrollDispatcher) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      this.toppingList.push({ id: i, viewValue: "option-" + i });
      this.toppingList1.push({ id: i, viewValue: "option-" + i });
    }
  }

  openChange($event: boolean) {
    if ($event) {
      this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort.scrollToIndex(0);
      this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort.checkViewportSize();
    }
  }

  openChange1($event: boolean) {
    if ($event) {
      this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort1.scrollToIndex(0);
      this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort1.checkViewportSize();
      
    }
  }


}
```

**this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort1.scrollToIndex(0);** scrolling to a particular index of second dropdown is also not working.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: a stackblitz is nice but please include minimal code example here also. Links can break

Comment: added minimal codes